# Windows 10 && Ubuntu 19.10, Windows drive no longer detected

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Update - I can no longer see the primary SSD, which contains the Windows boot. The computer has not moved since I started having this problem and updated to 19.10 which is when the problems began. Is there anything I can do?

I have been using a dual booted system for a while, and now I can no longer boot into Windows 10. Both OS have their own SSD in the system. I can boot into boot-repair, but not Windows 10. The results of the boot-repair are:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/r56MHyvZhz/

I have tried sudo-update grub, and boot-repair, to not luck. Please let me know if further info is needed, and if you have any ideas.

Thanks!

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: What happens when you try and boot into windows 10? and have you tried booting directly into it from the BIOS/UEFI boot menu seeing as it is on a seperate drive?

Comment: Boot-Repair only shows sda, no other drive? Also Ubuntu in UEFI mode on MBR drive which is not normal, but can work. UEFI normally uses gpt partitioning & Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot. Only evidence of Windows is an UEFI boot entry. Is Windows drive shown in UEFI (not boot, but drives)?